# Getting "Command find failed: Feature not supported" in .NET from AWS DocumentDb

Tags: mongodb-.net-driver, aws-documentdb

I am calling `myCollection.Find(_ => true)` in C# and getting this exception.
What can be wrong? What's not supported?
`db.MyDocs.find()` in mongosh works fine...

MongoDb.Driver 2.19.0,
DocumentDb engine version 4.0.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, this is what happened:

- the .NET driver translated the 'find' method call into the following MongoDB command:`{ "find" : "MyDocs", "filter" : { "$expr" : true } }`
- and DocoumentDB indeed does not support the `$expr` operator.

Took quite a while to figure out...

Comment: use `myCollection.Find("{}")`

Comment: @dododo This gets points for brevity, but not for expressiveness. This is the cleanest way I've found: `myCollection.Find(FilterDefinition<MyDoc>.Empty)`.

Comment: both will work, up to you